# Some users accessing published Sharepoint page Webpart of http links, see old http link, while most other users see the new, updated link

Tags: web-part, url, publishing-page, object-cache

We have a sharepoint page on our intranet that contains a webpart of http links to a number of tableau dashboards for teams to use for reporting purposes.

Periodically, the dashboards are refreshed and the web part is updated with one or more new Tableau URLs. The Sharepoint page is them submitted and has a status of 'published'

Most staff see the updated URL, but a small section of users still see the old link. Every user uses Internet Explorer to access the sharepoint page. I would surmise that the users only seeing the old URL have a local caching issue, maybe with the object cache. How does a user accessing the Sharepoint page with IE, refresh the cache so they can see the updated version of the Webpart with the new URLs?

Comment: Is this on-premises or online? Any specific reason you're still using IE? Ctrl + F5 for a hard refresh of the webpage which reloads both the page and the browsers cache. Should work but is a pretty ugly workaround.